# My flask app is not working. It says, "RuntimeError: Working outside of application context."

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I  have been using the udacity follow along for the Full stack nanodegree, however i'm stuck again

This is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://adai@localhost:5432/example'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'persons'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

This is what i  put in terminal:

```
FLASK_APP=flask-hello-app.py flask run
```

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1050, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 911, in run_command
    raise e from None
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 897, in run_command
    app = info.load_app()
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 308, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, name)
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/flask-hello-app.py", line 14, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 884, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 855, in _call_for_binds
    engine = self.engines[key]
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 636, in engines
    app = current_app._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "/Users/adai/class-demos/udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

I  tried to create a path using

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

```
export FLASK_RUN=$PATH:./udacity-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.2.3)
```

but that didn't help.

Is the path wrong, have i  not configured something right
Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this line `app.app_context().push()` after line `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`